# Compiling and older app to iPhone 6s shows a lower resolution

Tags: ios, iphone

Just got an iPhone 6S and started adjusting my project to it.
Somehow, when compiled and debugged on my iPhone, the view seems much smaller (like 4s).

- Xcode: 7.1.1
- iOS: 9.0.1
- IPHONE: 6S

Anyone knows that went wrong?

[image: SCREENSHOT1]
Thanks,

Comment: This could be an auto layout issue? Possibly change the auto layout constraints to fit your iPhone 6S as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include launch images for all the iPhone sizes if you want the app to use the native screen size.  The easiest way to do this is to migrate your launch images into an asset catalog.